# Вывод в форму модели с foreignkey, показывает pk, а не его текстовое поле. Django, python

Tags: python, django

Вывожу модель в форму и в поле, где `foreignkey` выводит `pk`, а не `name`. Как поменять вывод на поле `name`?

то есть выводит `pk` который записан в основной модели, а не поле имени `def __str__(self):`

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey('Device', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Устройство', related_name='get_device')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_orders', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Устройство')
    used = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**forms**

```
class SimpleOrderAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device']
        widgets = {
            'device': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'ajax-device', 'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}),
        }
```

**views**

```
class OrderEditView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_edit.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        get_order = Orders.objects.get(pk=context['order_id'])        
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(instance=get_order)
        context.update({'formOne': formOne})
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'order_edit' order_id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}      
    {{ formOne.non_field_errors }}
    {{ formOne.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

**picture**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем дело? почему выводит pk, а не name модели?

Comment: потому что TextInput, а не Select. Используйте автокомлит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как при проверке model foreign key, проверять не pk, а другое поле? django python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1277816/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5-model-foreign-key-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-pk-%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-django-pytho)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у вас есть 2 модели Статьи(**Article**) и Категории(**Category**), у статьи хранится внешний ключ на категорию. К примеру: `g = Category.objects.get(id=2)` - сделали запрос на определенную категорию из БД. И дальше мы хотим вывести статьи принадлежащие к этой категории. Так как у нас поле с **foreignkey** хранится в статьях(**Article**) мы воспользуемся **модель_set** ну или у поле со связью определим **related_name**(допустим posts), соответственно модель **Category** - первичная модель(с ней устанавливается связь),а **Article** - вторичная(в ней поле со связью). Теперь с помощью **related_name**(*posts*) обратимся к переменной **g**: `g.posts.all()`. Обьясняю: **g**- переменная, в которой находится категория, **posts**-*related_name* поля со связью статей и категория(это поле находится в статьях). То есть это такой "мост" между первичной моделью со вторичной(именно в таком порядке). И с помощью этого "моста" мы обращаемся к статьям в категории **g** и выводим их все (с помощью метода `all()` ),но допустим я хочу из определённой категории вывести определенную статью, это делается просто: мы делаем запрос на категорию,сохраняем её в переменную(допустим cat) и обращаемся к "мосту"  - posts,который выведет статьи в категории **cat**: `cat.posts.get(id=2)`. Если сказать в кратце, то из категории с `id=2`,мы запросили статью c **id=2**. Теперь эту статью запишем в context шаблона по ключу a. и в шаблоне при выводе `{{a.title}}` он выведет её заголовок, но допустим я хочу вывести категорию, к которой эта статья прикреплена. Очень просто! Я обращаюсь к полю со связью статей и категории(назовём его category-оно находится в Article): `{{a.cayegory}}` - выведете категорию статьи а, `{{a.category.title}}` - выведет имя категории статьи,а `{{a.category.pk}}` - выведет первичный ключ(цифру,а не строку с именем). Очень подробно обьяснил:)

Comment: а как вывести это в форме? форма же просто просит у меня поле device. или в форме как-то надо указать related_name?